# Extension for Array where Element is Optional

Tags: swift

I have an array of `String?` like so

```
var myArray: [String?] = ["2", "banana", nil, "31"];
```

I have another array of `String` like so:

```
var myStringArray: [String] = ["2", "3"]
```

I wrote an extension for Array to return me an Optional if index is not valid (which avoids the whole app crashing), but I really only want it to return Optional if the `Element` is NOT optional, and just return Element if it is Optional

```
    func safeIndex(_ index: Int) -> Element? {
        if self.indices.contains(index) {
            return self[index]
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

If i run this against `myArray` the resulting type is `String??`

```
let item = myArray.safeIndex(1) // item is String??
let strItem = myStringArray.safeIndex(99) // strItem is String?
```

How do i change my extension such that it gives me `String?` for BOTH cases

Note: If i am explicit about my types, I can get what I want like so

```
extension Array where Element == String? {
    func safeIndex(_ index: Int) -> String? {
        if self.indices.contains(index) {
            return self[index]
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

However, this approach requires me to write a bunch of extensions for a bunch of types i might have in an array which is a massive meh.

Comment: "How do i change my extension such that it gives me String? for BOTH cases" Why would you want it to? Your `safeIndex` returns `Element?`, i.e. it wraps the element in an Optional. That is what _you_ told it to do. If Element is String?, then a String?? is the right answer.

Comment: @matt added clarification `but I really only want it to return Optional if the `Element` is NOT optional, and just return Element if it is Optional`

Comment: But then you will get the wrong answer. `myArray`'s first element comes back to you as Optional("2"), you unwrap it to get "2", that's wrong, that's not what it is.

Comment: @matt it may be a `wrong` answer from the swift's type system POV, but as a normal human i just care if i have a value or I don't have a value, and i don't want my app crashing if indexes changed through user interaction but the button taps are lagging behind. I am trying to remove the need for checking index validity in a bunch of places. The double unwrap makes this approach annoying.

Comment: Then just check the index without the extra Optional wrap.

Comment: @matt so how do i do this in extension without being explicit about my types?

Comment: "i don't want my app crashing if indexes changed through user interaction but the button taps are lagging behind." This suggests a serious design error that needs to be fixed. If your data is changing out from under your UI in an uncontrolled way, this "safe" method won't save you. It'll prevent the crash that tells you about the bug, but replaces it with returning the wrong data (in a 100 element array, asking for element 10 in your example may actually give you element 9 or 8 or 11 or really just about anything). Your question isn't bad, but you should never use it for this purpose.

Comment: (Ask me about the time I made this exact design error and built a chat app where you accidentally could wind up chatting with the wrong person because the cells didn't match the indexes… on second thought, don't ask me. Given the people who wound up sending sensitive chat messages to the wrong person on their contact list, it's the closest I've ever been to losing my job over a bug. I deeply wish the app had crashed instead…)

Comment: @RobNapier Your example makes total sense, for things like rows in a table or items in a collection, but i am more referring to things like controllers nested in a view controller, where the server configuration changes such as those VCs user did not yet slide to are no longer valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of tricky but you can create an AnyOptional protocol that requires an associatedtype (Wrapped) and a computed property to return the optional type. Then you can return the element unwrapped if the index is valid otherwise return nil.

```
protocol AnyOptional {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Optional<Wrapped> { get }
}

extension Optional: AnyOptional {
    var optional: Optional<Wrapped> { self }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection  {
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element.Wrapped? where Element: AnyOptional {
        indices.contains(index) ? self[index].optional ?? nil : nil
    }
}
```

---

```
var myArray: [String?] = ["2", "banana", nil, "31"]
var myStringArray: [String] = ["2", "3"]

let item = myArray[safe: 1] // item is String?
let strItem = myStringArray[safe: 99] // strItem is String?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want could be achieved with two extensions and a dummy protocol, which would constrain the array's Element. Something like that:

```
protocol OptionalType {}
extension Optional: OptionalType {}

extension Array where Element: OptionalType {
    func safeIndex(_ index: Int) -> Element {
        return self[index]
    }
}

extension Array {
    func safeIndex(_ index: Int) -> Element? {
        if self.indices.contains(index) {
            return self[index]
        }
                
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then this would work:

```
var myArray: [String?] = ["2", "banana", nil, "31"];
var myStringArray: [String] = ["2", "3"]

let item = myArray.safeIndex(1)
print(type(of: item)) // Optional<String>
let strItem = myStringArray.safeIndex(99)
print(type(of: strItem)) // Optional<String>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as your extension is not a 'safe index'. If i change it to return nil i get `'nil' is incompatible with return type 'Element'`

Comment: I'm trying to tell you. Your whole safe index programme is untenable. There is a reason why arrays do not work this way.

Comment: @matt well it works if i am explicit about the `Element` type.

I just want to return sth like `default(Type)`