# Convert an optional Type to non-optional Type

Tags: swift, option-type, swift-keypath

The following code throws a compile error:

```
import UIKit

class Initable {
    required init() {}
}

class NestedObject:Initable {
    var nestedProp:String? = nil
}

class MyObj {
    var name:String? = nil
    var value:Int? = nil
    var otherVals:[String]? = nil
    var nestedObj:NestedObject? = nil
}

let obj = MyObj()
var nestedObj = obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj]
if(nestedObj == nil) {
    nestedObj = type(of: obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj]).init()
}
nestedObj![keyPath: \NestedObject.nestedProp] = "NEST ME BABY!!"
obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj] = nestedObj!

obj
```

This is due to the fact that `type(of: obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj])` is `NestedObject?`, which of course cannot be initialized. I need a way to unwrap the optional typing and get the non-optional typing `NestedObject`.

Assumptions that have to be maintained.

- I must used optionals as there is a chance for `nestedObj` to be nil.
- I do not know what the type `NestedObject` is. It could be any type, but I am assured those types are all `Initable`.
- I need to be able to set a property of my `nestedObject` via a keypath.
- If `nestedObject` is nil, I need to create a new `NestedObject` and set the value via a keypath.

This is a small part of a larger system, so the above assumptions must be considered. I cannot change those.

Comment: You're ok with the fact that at then end of this, obj.nestObj is still nil, and that you've modified an unrelated NestedObject? (That's what your current code would do if it worked the way you're describing.) That seems a very strange use case, and I'm suspect it's not what you mean. If that's not the case, it feels like MyObj.nestedObj just shouldn't be optional at all. Why can't it default to the "init" value? This class seems to be very heavy on Optionals for things that have obvious defaults (empty string, empty array, NestedObject()). Do the nil cases have a distinct meaning?

Comment: @RobNapier The end game is going to be to set that new object to the MyObj, but this little example issue highlights my problem. Part of the requirements is that nestedObj must be of type NestedObject?. This is a small part of a much larger system. I'll update the above to then set the nestedObj if that helps clarify things. The reason for all the optionals is because these objects tie back to API calls and form progression. nil meaning that value has not been set yet, so the optionals are a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your optional `Wrapped` type to initialize your nested object:

```
let obj = MyObj()
let nestedObj = type(of: obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj]).Wrapped()
nestedObj[keyPath: \NestedObject.nestedProp] = "NEST ME BABY!!"

print(nestedObj.nestedProp ?? "")  // "NEST ME BABY!!"
```

---

If you want the resulting object to be optional as well:

```
let obj = MyObj()
var nestedObj = obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj]
if nestedObj == nil {
    nestedObj = type(of: obj[keyPath: \MyObj.nestedObj]).Wrapped()
}
nestedObj?[keyPath: \NestedObject.nestedProp] = "NEST ME BABY!!"
```

---

You need to add those helpers:

```
protocol AnyOptional {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Optional<Wrapped> { get }
}

extension Optional: AnyOptional {
    var optional: Optional<Wrapped> { self }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. `Type of NestedObject? has no member Wrapped`

Comment: @steventnorris sorry I forgot to add the `AnyOptional` protocol and to conform `Optional` type to it.

Comment: Awesome! This does appear to work for my use case. I'm assuming there are no "gotchas" or side effects with basic optional behaviour?

Comment: No there is no disadvantages. You might be interested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64638268/2303865) as well